# Why am I getting "Cannot find symbol" error when I already defined the statements in another.java file?

Tags: java

Right now, I'm learning java before I start the semester so I can get the hang of it without struggling. At the moment, I'm having trouble compiling the current file I'm working on called RoomArea.java .

I get the error of not finding a symbol. For example:

> cannot find symbol
>
> symbol : method setLength
>
> location: variable kitchen of type Rectangle

Here is a snippet of my Rectangle.java file:

```
package rectangle;   

public class Rectangle 
{
     private double length;
     private double width;

     public void setLength(double l)
     {
         length = l;        

     }

     public void setWidth(double w)
     {
         width = w;         
     }

}
```

Here's where I get the errors of calling the functions from Rectangle.java into my RoomAreas.java file:

```
package roomarea;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RoomArea 
{


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  double number;
   double totalArea;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);




  /* Creating three Rectangle object */
 Rectangle bedroom = new Rectangle();
 Rectangle kitchen = new Rectangle();
 Rectangle den =  new Rectangle();

 /* Get and store the dimensions of the kitchen */
 System.out.print("What is the kitchen's length?");
 number = keyboard.nextDouble();
 kitchen.setLength(number);
 System.out.print("What is the kitchen's width? ");
 number = keyboard.nextDouble();
 kitchen.setWidth(number);

// ...
// ...
}
```

Comment: "`import java.awt.Rectangle;`" Which `Rectangle` class are you intending to use - yours, or `java.awt.Rectangle`?

Comment: My Rectangle class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're importing the wrong `Rectangle` class in `RoomArea`:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
```

should be

```
import rectangle.Rectangle;
```

(assuming you're actually trying to use your own `Rectangle` class).

Comment: I followed your suggestion. The symbol errors already went away, but now I'm getting a new error.

- error: package rectangle does not exist

Comment: @Marxy "I'm getting a new error" Assuming you want some help with that one too, you might need to provide a few more details.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to press shift + enter. Fixed it.

Comment: Is your Rectangle class on your classpath at compile time (with reference to the "package rectangle does not exist" error)?

Comment: @Riann No, the compile classpath is blank on the RoomArea.java file and same goes for Rectangle.java.

Comment: How are you compiling your code?  Off the command line using 'javac', or through an IDE?

Comment: @Riann IDE, I'm using Netbeans.

Comment: I decided to add the project Rectangle to my libraries by right-clicking Libraries on RoomArea and select Add Project. Then I added the Rectangle project and the error went away. Thanks for helping everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You are not using your own Rectangle class. Your are importing `java.awt.Rectangle`. Java will now interprete your three Rectangles as `java.awt.Rectangle` Objects.

Change

```
import Java.awt.Rectangle;
```

to

```
import rectangle.Rectangle;
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

found these issues with your code.
1. import proper rectangle
2. whatever you have pasted roomarea.java , needs one more "}" at the end.

Now compile class Rectangle.java from package rectangle and compile roomarea.java from roomarea like javac -cp ../ roomarea.java. this would create class files in respective folders.